# Passing post data in a rails app through a redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, redirect

This seems simple but I can't figure it out.  I receive post data in my rails app through a form and I want to use a redirect (instead of a render) but keep at least one of the pieces of post data alive through the redirect.  How can I do this?  Adding a hash on to redirect_to doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i have to do this in PHP, i store the POST data in the session, then i remove them when i'm done using them (There's even a pattern called "post / redirect / get" that tell to do this to avoid re-post of submitted data when reloading the page).

Couldn't you do what you want this way or something similar with Rails?

Comment: I can do this with the session.  The only reason I'm hesitant is that I'm not quite sure where to clear the variable (I don't really want to be resetting it on every page load).  If I don't reset the variable it will interfere down the road.

Comment: Couldn't you reset the variables just after you've finished using it in the page which you want to `redirect_to`? (Maybe what i'm saying is stupid, I don't really know RoR)

Comment: Don't worry that's not stupid, the only reason I can't do that is that I don't know what page the redirect is going to (it's set to redirect to the previous http request or the index page if one isn't set).

Comment: Then maybe you could add `?redir` at the end of the url which you redirect to and then you reset the session variables if there is a `redir` in the GET parameters of your url, but that means you have to test it on each page, so it may be as bad as the previous solutions...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [flash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Flash.html).